# Angular Type LifecycleStateManager does not have 'ɵmod' property

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

after install ngxs/devtools-plugin I got error and I don;t know why it's happend. I using angular 11

```
core.js:2124 Uncaught Error: Type LifecycleStateManager does not have 'ɵmod' property.
at getNgModuleDef (core.js:2124)
at recurse (core.js:24921)
at recurse (core.js:24932)
at recurse (core.js:24932)
at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24917)
at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:25031)
at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:28586)
at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:28824)
at Module.zUnb (main.ts:11)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

Comment: did you place devtools module at root app module's imports array?

Comment: I added NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot()

Answer (score 0):

Run following command:
npm ci

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error when using a library which specified (in `peerDependencies`) a different version of ngxs (at patch level :-o). I got it running by setting the exactly same version in both.

My application used:

```
"@ngxs/store": "3.7.2",
```

and the library:

```
"@ngxs/store": "^3.7.0",
```

So, you might want to make sure that the `ngxs/devtools-plugin` has the exactly same version as your `ngxs/store`.

**UPDATE**: actually an delete of `node_modules` + `npm install` solved the issue for the different patch version.
But this difference of ngxs version between the lib and the app (major/minor) already caused us similar "emod" errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had error *page.module does not have 'ɵmod' property.*

I removed `providers:[]` from my **page.module.ts**.